# When are non-homogeneous sets first encountered by students?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

My 5-year-old son recently brought home (from kindergarten) a worksheet that he had done at school. 6 boxes were given. In one box were 3 kites, in another, 2 bears, in another 8 drums, and so on. Each box had a list of 3 numbers at the bottom to choose from. The instructions were:

“Count the objects in each set. Draw a circle around the right number.”

As we all know, such exercises are common for young students, but I have always wondered whether such exercises were teaching something that would later have to be unlearned, namely, the false idea that members of a set are always all instances of the same thing. Anyway, at the very least we should ask when in their academic career students finally encounter the truth that the members of a set can be things of different type. 8th grade? senior year of high school? College? Only math majors in college after their first year?

Comment: Depending on the materials/instructor, it might well come this year. You could have students count people in their family (all "people" but not all the same in the way that I imagine, e.g., the depicted kites are). Or you might have students look at a box with cats *and* dogs, and have them count the cats, then count the dogs, then count the total number of animals. See, for example, [**here**](http://education.ohio.gov/getattachment/Topics/Early-Learning/Early-Learning-Content-Standards/Implementation-Guide-Cognitive-Development-and-General-Knowledge.pdf.aspx) on p. 13 (under Pre-K).

Answer (score 4):

It is very early primary school that they learn that sets can hold instances of different things. If they are of the same thing, then they are not really sets - or rather they have cardinality 1 as sets can't have repetition.

However, It is a good that they learn early on that set should contain things of the same type. A set of 3 apples can be unioned (added) with a set of 2 oranges, but what would the result be? Not a set of apples or oranges, but a set of 5 pieces of fruit. And then add in a dog, and you have a set of 6 formerly alive objects. Add in a cloud...

The more varied the type of thing in the set, the less you can do with it. For instance, you could have a set of a person, a name, a number, and mathematical equation and the set of prime numbers, but I can't imagine what you would ever do with it. What would be the point of counting it (5 items)? What kind of set would you intersect it with?

In Computer Science, arrays, lists, or sets are often typed to prevent randomly heterogenous sets. Tuples, records, or structs may contain heterogenous objects, but they can not be manipulated as sets.

Comment: The importance given to heterogeneous sets seems to me to be an inadequate consequence of the choice of set theory as a foundation of mathematics. Maybe a type-oriented approach as homotopy type theory might change that.

Comment: (Why is the dog "formerly alive"?!)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman the picture of it on the worksheet did not look very animated

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, are picked pieces of fruit still alive?  (I don't know.)  Maybe it was just the most general descriptor that came to mind for the elements of a set containing fruit and a dog!

Comment: “I can't imagine what you would ever do with it” - "A failure of imagination is not an insight into necessity." -- Patrick Barrow

Comment: @MikeJones The burden of proof is on you that they are generally useful if you are suggesting that curricula be changed to accomodate the "necessity" of heterogenous sets. Homogenous sets are not a "false idea", they are a necessary restriction for sets to be useful or meaningful in a majority of situations. Similarly, should we teach students that the law of the excluded middle is itself neither true nor false? It just happens to be very useful in the majority of situations. Most maths majors graduate without worrying about issues like this, let alone primary school students :-)

Comment: @Richard: The sets are more than homogeneous - they are cookie cutter. The set of real numbers, for example, on the other hand, contains many different types of numbers.

Comment: @MikeJones are you objecting to homogenous types {2,3,4} or references to the same object {2,2,2}, the latter having a size of 1 rather than 3? Are you objecting that the bears are not visually distinguishable from each other so that they appear to be the same object? I can understand this objection, though historically sets of indistinguishable commodities symbolised by "cookie cutter" images pressed into clay led to the invention of numbers and mathematics, so even this is probably sound pedagogically.